# Can omnet be run faster than express mode?

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++, inet

Is there a way to run the simulation faster no UI/all cores? Currently I'm using express mode but it's still very slow for large networks (> 100 nodes). One simulated ms ~= 1 real life s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. First of all, build your model in release mode.
Then start your simulation in [Cmdenv](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:run-sim:cmdenv) mode - take a look at [Chapter 6.3.3 Creating a Launch Configuration](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/UserGuide.pdf).